# Attaching a Custom Taxonomy to Posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Say a plugin creates a custom taxonomy and attaches it to some custom post type. Is there a safe way to attach that same taxonomy to Posts?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`register_taxonomy_for_object_type`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) function and if you say that the taxonomy is created by a plugin you can use the `plugins_loaded` hook, to make sure that taxonomy wast already registered so:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded','add_custom_taxonomy_to_posts');

function add_custom_taxonomy_to_posts(){
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('TAXONOMY_NAME', 'post');
}
```

Comment: While this is correct WordPress dictates you should register Custom Post Types & Taxonomies on the init hook IIRC.

Comment: accept you can't be sure when the taxonomy is registered, so you call it after the plugins are loaded